# Plotting optimum as a function of parameter in the objective

Tags: optimization, constrained-optimization, scipy

I am trying to minimize a 2d function using scipy.optimize. Specifically I want to plot the minimum value of the function **fun** as a function of the parameter **wjk**. The problem is that I cannot pass **wjk** as a function argument as I am not optimizing over it. How to obtain the optimized value as a function of a parameter in the objective function?

````
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mp
from scipy.stats import lognorm
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from numdifftools import Jacobian, Hessian

def fun(y):
    li = 1e4
    wj = 0.1
    wk = 0.4
    wjk = 0.2
    pji = 1 - lognorm.cdf(y[0], 10)
    pki = 1 - lognorm.cdf(y[1], 10)
    return (li*(wj * pji + wk * pki - wjk * pji * pki ) + y[0] + y[1])

def fun_der(x):
    return Jacobian(lambda x: fun(x))(x).ravel()

def fun_hess(x):
    return Hessian(lambda x: fun(x))(x)

def main():

    y0 = [100.0, 100.0]
    b = (0, np.inf)
    bounds = (b, b)
    y=minimize(fun, y0, bounds=bounds, method='SLSQP', jac=fun_der, hess=fun_hess).__getitem__('x')
    print(y, fun(y))


main()```
````

Comment: I think that you could improve the title, it does not seem related to plotting

Answer (score 1):

There are several way to do this. For instance, you can define a new function fun_wjk(y) = fun(y, wjk) each time that you want to do a minimization with a different value of wjk.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mp
from scipy.stats import lognorm
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from numdifftools import Jacobian, Hessian

def fun(y, wjk_value):
    li = 1e4
    wj = 0.1
    wk = 0.4
    wjk = wjk_value
    pji = 1 - lognorm.cdf(y[0], 10)
    pki = 1 - lognorm.cdf(y[1], 10)
    return (li*(wj * pji + wk * pki - wjk * pji * pki ) + y[0] + y[1])

def fun_der(x, wjk_value):
    return Jacobian(lambda x: fun(x, wjk_value))(x).ravel()

def fun_hess(x, wjk_value):
    return Hessian(lambda x: fun(x, wjk_value))(x)

def main(wjk):

    y0 = [100.0, 100.0]
    b = (0, np.inf)
    bounds = (b, b)
    fun_wjk = lambda y : fun(y, wjk_value=wjk)
    fun_der_wjk = lambda y : fun_der(y, wjk_value=wjk)
    fun_hess_wjk = lambda y : fun_hess(y, wjk_value=wjk)
    y=minimize(fun_wjk, y0, bounds=bounds, method='SLSQP', jac=fun_der_wjk, hess=fun_hess_wjk).__getitem__('x')
    print(y, fun_wjk(y))


main(wjk=0.15)
main(wjk=0.2)
main(wjk=0.25)
```

You can also pass wjk as an argument to fun, as indicated in the [scipy.optimize.minimize documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html). It also passes the arguments to the Jacobian and the Hessian.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mp
from scipy.stats import lognorm
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from numdifftools import Jacobian, Hessian

def fun(y, *args):
    li = 1e4
    wj = 0.1
    wk = 0.4
    try:
        wjk = args[0]
    except Exception:
        wjk = 0.2
    pji = 1 - lognorm.cdf(y[0], 10)
    pki = 1 - lognorm.cdf(y[1], 10)
    return (li*(wj * pji + wk * pki - wjk * pji * pki ) + y[0] + y[1])

def fun_der(x, *args):
    return Jacobian(lambda x: fun(x, *args))(x).ravel()

def fun_hess(x, *args):
    return Hessian(lambda x: fun(x, *args))(x)

def main(wjk):

    y0 = [100.0, 100.0]
    b = (0, np.inf)
    bounds = (b, b)
    y=minimize(fun, y0, bounds=bounds, args=(wjk,), method='SLSQP', jac=fun_der, hess=fun_hess).__getitem__('x')
    print(y, fun(y))


main(wjk=0.15)
main(wjk=0.2)
main(wjk=0.25)
```

Comment: Getting an error for the second code:     return Jacobian(lambda x: fun(x, wjk=wjk))(x).ravel() 
TypeError: fun() got an unexpected keyword argument 'wjk'

Comment: my bad, *args should just be passed from fun_der or fun_hess to fun as an argument. This should work now.